# Why AngularJS view doesn't change when navigating?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new in angularJS. I write some code for navigation and it was work perfect. But it's stop working when I integrate [MetroPreLoader](http://codecanyon.net/item/metro-preloader/3786559) in my angularJs service. It change browser URL but view does not update. if i remove MetroPreLoader from my service then it`s works again.

Here is my Code :

Service :

```
voiceAppControllers.factory('appService', function ($http, $log, $window) {
    return {

        showWaitBar : function() {
            MetroPreLoader.setup({
                logoUrl: "Content/Images/logo.png",
                logoWidth: "100px",
                logoHeight: "100px",
                multipleBGColors: ["#CA3D3D", "#F58A16", "#32A237", "#A110E6"],
                delay: "Unlimited"
            });
            MetroPreLoader.run();
        },

        hideWaitbar : function() {
            MetroPreLoader.close();
        }
    };
})
```

Controller :

```
voiceAppControllers.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$timeout', 'appService', 'notificationService',
    function ($scope, $http, $location,$timeout, appService, notificationService) {
        var onSuccess = function () {
            notificationService.pushNotifaction("service update successfully.");
        };

        var onError = function () {
            notificationService.pushNotifaction("service update fail.");
        };

        $scope.login = function () {
            var credentials = "grant_type=password&username=" + $scope.loginModel.Username + "&password=" + $scope.loginModel.Password;
            console.log(credentials);

            appService.showWaitBar();
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: appService.loginUrl,
                data: credentials,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
            })
                .success(function (data) {
                    console.log(data.access_token);
                    appService.updateAuthInfo(data.userName, data.access_token);
                    appService.hideWaitbar();
                    $location.path(appService.routes.dahboard);
                })
                .error(function () {
                    appService.clearAuthInfo();
                    appService.hideWaitbar();
                    $location.path(appService.routes.login);
                    notificationService.pushNotifaction("Login Fail. Wrong username and password.");
                });
        };

    }
]);
```

when i comment `appService.showWaitBar()` and `appService.hideWaitbar()` then its works fine.

[image]

I defiantly miss something but don`t figure out that it is.

Thnaks.

Update 1:

my App.js is :

```
var voiceAppControllers = angular.module('voiceAppControllers', []);

var voiceApp = angular.module('voiceApp', ['ngRoute', 'voiceAppControllers', 'kendo.directives']);

voiceApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        when('/organization', {
            templateUrl: 'Templates/OrganizationTemplate.html',
            controller: 'organizationController'
        }).when('/service', {
            templateUrl: 'Templates/ServiceTemplate.html',
            controller: 'serviceController'
        }).when('/login', {
           templateUrl: 'Templates/LoginTemplate.html',
           controller: 'serviceController'
        }).when('/Dashboard', {
           templateUrl: 'Templates/DashboardTemplate.html',
           controller: 'dashboardController'
       }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/login'
        });
  }]);
```

Login View is :

```
<div ng-controller="loginController">
    <form name="loginFrom" novalidate ng-submit="login(loginFrom)">
        <input type="hidden" ng-model="loginModel.Id" />

        <h1>Login</h1>
        <label>Need Some Text</label>
        <div>
            <label>username :</label>
            <div class="input-control text">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Your username" required ng-model="loginModel.Username" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>password :</label>
            <div class="input-control password">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Your password" required ng-model="loginModel.Password" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="offset3">
            <input class="primary" type="submit" value="UPDATE" ng-disabled="loginFrom.$invalid" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

my Dashboard View is :

```
<div ng-controller="dashboardController">
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    <input type="button" value="Next" />
</div>
```

Comment: I have to admit that I'm not very experienced, and I'd probably benefit from seeing more code, but I suspect that one error is that "dashboard" is spelled improperly: "appService.routes.dahboard"

Comment: have you tried adding $scope.$apply() after $location.path?

Comment: @AlexChoroshin unfortunately i dont see any $scope dependent templating here, so I dont know if $scope.$apply would make any difference

Comment: If you're not already using it, get Batarang Chrome extension to help debug this in stages. No JS console errors?

Comment: @ChrisBell there is no JS console errors and every goes fine without update view.

Comment: @BrandonParmenter Add more Code. Please take a look.

Comment: @Hasan009 You've only shown us loginController, but your routes are calling for organizationController, serviceController, and dashboardController. You've misspelled notification ("pushNotifaction") and dashboard ("appService.routes.dahboard"). I'm not very good at this stuff yet, and I have no experience with MetroPreLoader, and you take a different approach to JavaScript than I do, so overall I just feel like I can't help you. Sorry. :/